# Query data from two associated tables

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

For my app:

- user has_many images, image belongs_to user
- image has_one location, location belongs_to image

Perhaps the location's fields should just be part of the image. But regardless, I'm trying to write this query in Rails:

```
    SELECT image.caption, location.latitude, location.longitude 
    FROM   image, location 
    WHERE  location.image_id = image.id 
    AND    image.user_id = 5
```

or alternatively, if it's easier:

```
    SELECT  image.*, location.*
    FROM    image, location
    WHERE   location.image_id = image.id 
    AND     image.user_id = 5
```

How would I write this as an ActiveRecord query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to read about **[Eager Loading Associations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#eager-loading-associations)**.

```
@images = Image.includes(:location).where("images.user_id = ?", 5)
```

This will find `Image` instances where `user_id = 5`. It then runs a 2nd query that will `JOIN` and build the associated `Location` instance *(thats what the `.includes(:location)` will do for you)*.

This more closely matches your alternative query, as it does select all columns from `images` and `location` tables.

You can build an Array based on this containing a hash with only the keys you're interested in through something like this.

```
@hash_object = @images.collect { |i| { caption: i.caption, latitude: i.location.latitude, longitude: i.location.longitude } }
```

---

If you want to build this with only a single query, you can use `.joins(:location)` in combination with `.includes(:location)`

```
Image.joins(:location).includes(:location).where("images.user_id = ?", 5)
```

**Important:** This will omit `Image` instances who have no assoicated `Location`. You can modify the `joins()` a bit to help with this, but the above will have this omission.

---

If you **really** want only specific columns to be selected, read up on **[Selecting Specific Columns](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#selecting-specific-fields)** though there are warnings for the use of this

> If the select method is used, all the returning objects will be read only.

and

> Be careful because this also means you’re initializing a model object with only the fields that you’ve selected.

---

In Rails master (not out in 3.2.11) you can pass *multiple columns* to [`.pluck()`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/relation/calculations.rb#L111) but this appears to only be restricted to a single table *(you wouldn't be able to get the `locations` table's `:latitude` and `:longitude` when plucking from `Image`)*. It's good to know about though.

Comment: Thanks, that works! Much better than the query in a loop that was happening before. 

I notice in the logs it's still querying the Location and Image tables separately in two queries though; I wonder if there's a way around that. 
Thanks again for the help!

Comment: Updated my answer for you. Please, accept/up-vote my answer if it's fixed your problem.